# setting variables equal to 'gets' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I want to write a program that asks for two strings from the user and searches for one within the other, but I'm having some trouble making it work. The following returns "not" even when the given character is present within the string. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
puts 'Enter the string that you would like to search'
content = gets
puts 'What character would you like to find?'
query = gets
if content.include? query
  puts "here"
else
  puts "not"
end
```

Comment: You should probably be using `.chomp` when getting input from the user. Otherwise the newline character will be present.

Answer (score 1):

`gets` returns the string from the user including the newline character '\n' at the end. If the user enters "Hello world" and "Hello", then the strings really are:

```
"Hello World\n"
"Hello\n"
```

That makes it obvious, why your code does not find a match.

Use [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) to remove that newline characters from the end of the string.

```
puts 'Enter the string that you would like to search'
content = gets.chomp

puts 'What character would you like to find?'
query = gets.chomp

if content.include?(query)
  puts "here"
else
  puts "not"
end
```